# Display real time cab movement with Uber sdk iOS

Tags: ios, uber-api

We are integrating Uber SDK in our native iOS and android apps.
How can we show real time cab movement once ride is started with Uber in my app?

Answer (score 2):

For reaching driver position in real time, after a Ride Request is accepted you could use endpoint Ride Request / Map.

```
GET /v1.2/requests/{request_id}/map
```

Where {request_id} is unique identifier representing a Request.

More about using this endpoint can be found [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-map-get).

This endpoint requires a privileged scope to be used in production by all Uber riders. You can use this endpoint immediately when authenticated as yourself or any of your 5 registered developers. When you are ready to distribute your application broadly for use by all Uber riders, you may request FULL ACCESS. For more information read about scopes.